# Heroku error -“Command errored out with exit status 1” while deploying python through the Heroku/Git plugin

Tags: python, git, heroku, compiler-errors, command-prompt

When I try to deploy python through the Heroku/Git plugin, I get this error:

```
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Complete logs here: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/cexofeluha.sql

Can anyone help me please? What does the error mean?
I had this error multiple times now. What can I do?
I am trying to hast a discord.py bot.
I don't have anymore details, what can I do?

Comment: `Running command git clone -q https://github.com/MetalManiac1331/raidbot /tmp/pip-req-build-6nv06flr` use the clone directory in some local path as you don;t need to do sudo permission to access the /tmp folder

Answer (score 0):

You have `git+https://github.com/MetalManiac1331/raidbot` in your `requirements.txt` but the repository is not a `pip`-installable Python package — it doesn't have `setup.py`. Currently it doesn't have any Python files at all.

Remove that broken package from `requirements.txt`, commit and push again.